# Python Selenium Internet Explorer scripts don't work

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

If I make a simple script like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service
import os
from pathlib import Path

path = Path().absolute()
path = os.path.join(path, 'IEDriverServer')
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=path)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
print("ANYTHINGGG")
```

Selenium opens the Edge on IE mode (no problem), opens google, but after that it stops... don't print "ANYTHINGGG" and I cannot program anything after `driver.get('https://www.google.com/')`.

This problem seems to be in any site.

Anyone has a clue of what can solve that?

(I am using windows 10, python 3.7.9)

Just expect that the code do not stops on `driver.get('https://www.google.com/')`

Comment: Only happening with IE?

Comment: Yes, chrome works fine, but it's necessary the IE on my work..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate Edge IE mode with IEDriver, you need to:

1. Define `InternetExplorerOptions` with additional properties that point to the Microsoft Edge browser.
2. Start an instance of `InternetExplorerDriver` and pass it `InternetExplorerOptions`. IEDriver launches Microsoft Edge and then loads your web content in IE mode.

You also need to meet the [Required Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=python#required-configuration). For detailed information about using Internet Explorer Driver to automate IE mode in Edge, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=python).

Your code seems not right, you can refer to the following code, it works well (change the path in the code to your owns):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service

ser = Service("E:\\webdriver\\IEDriverServer.exe")
ieOptions = webdriver.IeOptions()
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgechromium", True)
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgepath",'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe')
driver = webdriver.Ie(service = ser, options=ieOptions)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
print("ANYTHINGGG")
```

[image]

Comment: It still do not working, doing exactly like yours, the IEDriver version that I am using is  4.6.0.0 (the last one today), you may think that the driver may be causing the problem? If so, would you hava a link to an older version? (I just dinnot find an older version on internet)

Comment: "The driver executable needs to be placed in the PATH" means that I need to put the location of the driver on my "environment variables" ?

Comment: I use Python 3.9.5. I test with 32-bit Windows IE Driver 4.6.0.0 and it still works, so I think the driver version is OK. For your second question, yes, you need to put IE driver location on **Environment Variables -> Path**. Besides, please don't forget to **meet all the [Required Configuration](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ie_driver_server/#required-configuration)**. And which version of Selenium do you use? I use **Selenium 4.3.0**.

Comment: It worked now, I needed to set the registry entry that says on the Required Configuration